# ApexSQL code completion doesn't work after a CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, intellisense, ssms-addin

I have the ApexSQL Complete add-in for SSMS and it’s working with a SQL Server database. Anytime I write a query with the `CROSS APPLY` feature, code completion stops working for my SQL code.

An example query that seems to break the code autocomplete after the `JOIN` keyword:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [User].[User] u
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [Curriculum].[Enrollment] e
    WHERE e.IdUser = u.Id
    ORDER BY e.EndDate DESC
) as Enrollment
JOIN --STOPS WORKING HERE
WHERE u.Id = 19521
```

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug report or open a support ticket with the Apex people. No one here is likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I thought that it might be a problem with my configurations.

Comment: That may be possible, though if it's true I also don't know how you expect anyone to help you without also posting that configuration info.

Comment: In addition, for enhanced clarity, please provide the smallest bit of your code/query for which this issue exists and the database type you're working with.  Intellisense is not an ApexSQL product.

Comment: It's ApexSQL Complete, when i put a CROSS APPLY in any of my queries, if i try to do a JOIN after it, the intellisense from ApexSQL doesn't work

Comment: What database type are you working with?  MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server?  It's probably the latter, but I want to make sure since Intellisense (as it's a Microsoft product) is going to work best with SQL Server but might apply to another type of DBMS as well.  Providing this info will help give your question greater visibility because it will be properly tagged on SO (Stack Overflow).

Comment: It's Sql Server

Comment: Are you using ApexSQL Complete in SSMS or in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using it in SSMS

Comment: @SimãoSantos  I'm waiting for a moderator to approve my updates to your question with tags more relevant to your situation.  But more info from you is still needed - otherwise you risk this question will be closed by a moderator.  Database code completion can fail when tables aren't aliased properly in the offending query.  Please update your question with the actual SQL of the *simplest* query that breaks the autocomplete feature for you.  If you need guidance about what I mean by "simplest" please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added an example, dont know if its good enough

Comment: @SimãoSantos yes, that was good enough.  Your question has been edited to allow more people to find it and hopefully respond to it.  Can you confirm that the sql query you've provided actually executes without issue? (that would rule out a possible syntax/parsing error)

Comment: It does execute, it's just the autocomplete that stops working